# How to sort by columns within a search result without displaying all rows again after sorting

Tags: search, sort, wp-list-table

I want to display a WP_List_Table on a submenu_page and offer a search function.

The display of the data works so far and also the search, but the column sorting causes problems. If I click on the column to sort it will be sorted and all data will be displayed. If I search for a keyword, I get a modified table accordingly, I click on a column to sort it, I get all data displayed again - but I want to sort within my search results, how can I achieve this?

I've been looking for a solution for some time and haven't found anything yet. Either I'm stumped or I'm just pretty stupid. Either way, I would be happy if someone could help me.

**Please note:**
I'm new to the world of programming, so please forgive me all my unknowingness and stupidity!

Below is the complete source code of the page:

```
if (!class_exists('WP_List_Table'))
{
    require_once ('../../assets/lib/class-wp-list-table.php');
}

class My_List_Table extends WP_List_Table
{

    public function no_items()
    {
        _e('Unfortunately there are no ingredients available :(', 'wp-my-recipe');
    }
    /**
     * Prepare the items for the table to process
     *
     * @return Void
     */
    public function prepare_items($search = NULL)
    {
        $data = $this->table_data($search);
        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = $this->get_hidden_columns();
        $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();
        $perPage = 1;
        $currentPage = $this->get_pagenum();
        if (!is_null($data))
        {
            $totalItems = count($data);
            $data = array_slice($data, (($currentPage - 1) * $perPage) , $perPage);
        }
        else
        {
            $totalItems = 0;
        }
        $this->set_pagination_args(array(
            'total_items' => $totalItems,
            'per_page' => $perPage
        ));
        $this->_column_headers = array(
            $columns,
            $hidden,
            $sortable
        );
        $this->items = $this->table_data($search);
    }
    /**
     * Override the parent columns method. Defines the columns to use in your listing table
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public function get_columns()
    {
        $columns = array(
            'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />', // to display the checkbox.
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => __('Ingredient name', 'wp-my-recipe') ,
            'kcalories' => __('Kilocalories per 100 ml/mg', 'wp-my-recipe') ,
            'reference' => __('Reference value', 'wp-my-recipe')
        );
        return $columns;
    }
    /**
     * Define which columns are hidden
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public function get_hidden_columns()
    {
        return array(
            'id'
        );
    }
    /**
     * Define the sortable columns
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public function get_sortable_columns()
    {
        return array(
            'name' => array(
                'name',
                false
            ) ,
            'kcalories' => array(
                'kcalories',
                false
            ) ,
            'reference' => array(
                'reference',
                false
            ) ,
        );
    }
    /**
     * Get the table data
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    function table_data($search = NULL)
    {

        //todo add real search
        if ($search != NULL)
        {
            $search = trim($search);
            $data = array(
                ['id' => 'dummyData',
                'name' => $search,
                'kcalories' => 'dummyData',
                'reference' => 'dummyData']
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $data = s_getAllIngredients();
        }

        return $data;
    }
    /**
     * Define what data to show on each column of the table
     *
     * @param  Array $item        Data
     * @param  String $column_name - Current column name
     *
     * @return Mixed
     */
    public function column_default($item, $column_name)
    {
        switch ($column_name)
        {
            case 'id':
            case 'name':
            case 'kcalories':
            case 'reference':
                return $item[$column_name];
            default:
                return print_r($item, true);
        }
    }
    // /**
    //  * Allows you to sort the data by the variables set in the $_GET
    //  *
    //  * @return Mixed
    //  */
    private function sort_data($a, $b)
    {

        // Set defaults
        $orderby = 'name';
        $order = 'asc';
        // If orderby is set, use this as the sort column
        if (!empty($_GET['orderby']))
        {
            $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
        }
        // If order is set use this as the order
        if (!empty($_GET['order']))
        {
            $order = $_GET['order'];
        }
        $result = strcmp($a[$orderby], $b[$orderby]);
        if ($order === 'asc')
        {
            return $result;
        }
        return -$result;

    }

    protected function column_cb($item)
    {
        return sprintf('<label class="screen-reader-text" for="ingredient_' . $item['id'] . '">' . sprintf(__('Select %s') , $item['name']) . '</label>' . "<input type='checkbox' name='ingredient[]' id='ingredient_{$item['id']}' value='{$item['id']}' />");
    }

}

$myListTable = new My_List_Table();

//Fetch, prepare, sort, and filter our data...
if (isset($_POST['s']))
{
    $myListTable->prepare_items($_POST['s']);
}
else
{
    $myListTable->prepare_items();
}

echo "<form role='search' method='post' id='searchform'>";
$myListTable->search_box("Search", "search_post_id");
echo "</form>";

$myListTable->display();
```